# How to test an observable stream?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, rxjs, observable

I want to write unit tests in Angular for the following function:

```
exportToCsv(query: string) {
    this.exportToCsvService.exportDataAndGetCsv(query).pipe(
      first(),
      tap(response => this.fireCsvDownload(response))
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

The function exportDataAndGetCsv makes a http call and returns a string. I think the test I would write should check if the fireCsvDownload was executed. I tried:

```
it('should fire fireCsvDownload after exporting data and geting csv ', () => {
    component.exportToCsv(query);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.fireCsvDownload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But I get an error: `Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.` What should I do? I provide the `exportToCsv` service to the `TestBed` and the `exportDataAndGetCsv` returns `of('text').`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a spy which you replace in the `expect`:

```
it('should fire fireCsvDownload after exporting data and geting csv ', () => {

    const mySpy = spyOn(component, 'fireCsvDownload');
    component.exportToCsv(query);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

You might have to do:

```
const mySpy = spyOn(component, 'fireCsvDownload').and.callThrough();
```

But I'm not certain without testing myself.

Comment: Ok great, I'll leave it though in case someone else might need to add it in the future.